# Why does the output signals post-synthesis not work as usual?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus, register-transfer-level

I had written a small VHD file for simulating the behavior of a quadrature decoder, enclosed below. Simulating the design with a generic testbench works as expected. But after generating a synthesizable design with Quartus, I run into one of two problems (while playing with using *unsigned*, for example)
1. The `position` and `direction` signal are always at a constant 0 value throughout the post-synthesis simulation.
2. The `position` value seems to jump 10 values every 3-4 clock cycles, which I attribute to some jitter in data.
Does anyone have any recommendations to solve this issue? Is this mainly a timing problem or is there a major flaw in my design?

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity quad_decoder is
  port(rst   : in  std_logic;
       clk   : in  std_logic;
       a    : in  std_logic;
       b    : in  std_logic;
       direction : out std_logic;
       position : out std_logic_vector(8 DOWNTO 0));
end quad_decoder;


architecture behavioral of quad_decoder is
begin
    process(clk)
        variable counter : integer range 0 to 360 := 0;
        variable chanA,chanB : std_logic;
        variable int_direction : std_logic; 
            begin
                if (rst = '0') then 
                    int_direction := '0';
                    counter := 0;
                elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then                   
                    chanA := a;
                    chanB := b;
                    if (chanA = '1') and (chanB = '0') then
                        if (counter = 360) then
                            counter := 0;
                        else
                            counter:= counter + 1;
                        end if;
                        int_direction := '1';
                    elsif (chanA = '0') and (chanB = '1') then
                        if (counter = 0) then 
                            counter := 360; 
                        else 
                            counter := counter-1;
                        end if;
                        int_direction := '0';
                    else
                        counter := counter;
                        int_direction := int_direction;
                    end if;
                    position <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(counter,9));
                    direction <= int_direction;
                end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

The expected pre-synthesis snap is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANgiO.png).

I've linked an example snap of the post-synthesis simulation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAtKy.png). As seen, no change to `position` nor `direction` in multiple clock cycles.

Comment: Im surprised this synthesised at all. Using both clock edges is not allowed in FPGAs. I think you get away with it because it appears none of the logic is set in both edges, hence the `counter` and `direction` registers are clocked on the rising, and `position` and `direction` on the falling edge. Have you run this through timing analysis? are you aware by using both edges like this the routing delay between counter and poistion must be less than half a clock? usually everything is done with a single edge.

Comment: Would you suggest performing the assignments within the `else rising_edge(clk)` portion or outside the main if-condition block? I've run this through Timing Analysis and got the all-green but running the `hard-block` design in ModelSim just introduces a whole lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is inquisitive, doing assignments right at the clock edge as well as turning the reset signal high proved to introduce all kinds of timing issues, which passed the multi-corner timing analysis test, but failed other tests in Quartus that I had failed to notice.

I can go into more details if my answer is vague.